# WSO2 esb get attach files from email

Tags: file, email, wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I am trying with WSO2 ESB to get an email (pop mail) with attach files and put all theses attach files in a folder with vfs. So I create a proxy service with MailTransportListener. I manage to get the email message but I don't know how to extract all attach files from the email and save them to a local folder. Here is my Proxy service.

Thank for your help.

Nicolas

```
`<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MailProxy"
       transports="mailto"
      statistics="enable"
      trace="enable"
   startOnLoad="true">
 <target>
  <inSequence>
     <property name="senderAddress" expression="get-property('transport', 'From')"/>
     <property name="filename" expression="get-property('transport', 'filename')"/>
     <property name="AttachmentFile"
               expression="stat.csv"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <property name="transport.mail.Format"
               value="Attachment"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED"
               value="true"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <property name="messageType" value="binary/attachment" scope="axis2"/>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
     <log level="full">
        <property name="Sender Address" expression="get-property('filename')"/>
     </log>
     <send>
        <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_A1546EFFD75FC9CCED785986339425964585275">
           <address uri="vfs:file:///home"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
     <drop/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="enableMTOM">false</parameter>
  <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.port">995</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
  <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
  <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">user@gmail.com</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="mail.pop3.host">pop.gmail.com</parameter>
  <parameter name="mail.pop3.password">mdp</parameter>
  <parameter name="mail.pop3.user">user</parameter>
  <parameter name="mail.pop3.port">995</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">pop3</parameter>
  <description/>
 </proxy>'
```

Comment: was the article below (answer of Erno) useful to you? And did you find a solution? I am looking for a similar thing. Trying to extract email attachment from mail and save them in a local directory. Did you see a similar example/article on the net?

Comment: Hi, I'm interested in that use case too. I managed to read email with IMAP protocol but I'm still searching how to extract email attachments to process them...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following article helps:

http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/06/saving-mtom-attachments-using-vfs-transport/

Comment: It's very old article possible that there isn't a more easy solution ?